# $_POST in array writing to CSV returns error PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, post, csv

I'm trying to get form data from an HTML form to be added into a serverside excel csv file. When I try creating the csv file, and writing to it with $_POST values from the HTML form, I get an error saying: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' in process.php on line 46". I'e tried a few alterations of the following code to see if I could get it to work, but nothing so far. Any help would be very appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$list = array (
    array('$_POST['some_field']', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way too many quotes in there, you don't need them around the $_POST variable.

```
$list = array (
    array($_POST['some_field'], 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);
```

You can append to the file by using `'a'` instead of `'w'` in your `fopen` command:

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');
```

See the manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly now. Another question, if I try executing this code twice, it only changes the data in 'file.csv', while I would like to add to it. Is there a way I can append to the bottom of an already created file?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$some_field = $_POST['some_field'];
$list = array (
    array($some_field, 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('aaa', 'bbb')
);
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd go to the trouble of adding an extra variable and line of code? You also removed the `"` around aaa and bbb - maybe he/she wants those quoted.